# Check date range in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

So i'm having the following code of a jquery datepicker

```
$(".dateInput").datepicker({
    language:"el",
    format: " dd/mm/yyyy",
    startView: "+0d",
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    onClose: function() {
        .........
    }
})
```

and i would like to do a check on the `onClose`, where, if the date that the user selects is one month before the today date or one year after, an alert message would appear.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to restrict the user from entering these dates you can better use maxDate and minDate

Comment: I'm familiar with these, but i don't want restrictions, only an alert that would state a message i'm going to write. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow,
here is possible solution for your request:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $(".dateInput").datepicker({
      language: "el",
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      startView: "+0d",
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = new Date(dateText);

        var dateMin = new Date();
        dateMin.setMonth(dateMin.getMonth() - 1);
        dateMin.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set time to the beginning of the day

        var dateMax = new Date();
        dateMax.setFullYear(dateMax.getFullYear() + 1);
        dateMax.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // Set time to the end of the day

        if (date >= dateMin && date <= dateMax) {
          alert("Date is in range.");
        } else {
          alert("Date is NOT in range.");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="dateInput"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can find more info about Date object on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Instead of  `var date = new Date(dateText);` you can also use `var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, parseInt(inst.selectedDay));`.